# How can set the y and x axis of a wpf toolkit chart? something like y:kg, x:years

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, toolkit

Hi I would like to know how can i do to set the label for X axis and y axis?

Righ now, i have a chart with the values, and I format the tooltip, but i can't realize how to set the label for X an Y axis.

Another thing is, Is posible to execute zooming in a chart series, I mean, if i have the x axis in years, i would like to change it to months, or semesters and new points need to appear in the line? if this is posible, is too dificult to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't able to set the label of the y axis (I don't think its possible) but you could set it on the legend using the Title property. On the x axis it depends on the binding set on your DataPointSeries'IndependentValueBinding.

Lets say on this sample I have created a class object that will represent every record/datapoint.

```
public class ChartInfo
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have this code:

```
List<ChartInfo> list = new List<ChartInfo>();
ChartInfo item = new ChartInfo();
item.Label = "Individual";
item.Vale = 27;
list.Add(item);
item = new ChartInfo();
item.Label = "Corporate";
item.Vale = 108;
list.Add(item);

DataPointSeries series = new ColumnSeries();
series.Title = "Quantity";
series.DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value");
series.IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Label");
series.ItemsSource = list;
series.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(series_SelectionChanged);
this.chartingToolkitControl.Series.Add(series);
```

It will give me this result.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/78e2598620.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/78e2598620.jpg)

For the zooming - I think the right term is drill-down. You could use the SelectionChanged event (see the code above). What you should do is requery your datasource and clear the graph's series and add a new one based on your query result.

```
private void series_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //The sender here is of type DataPointSeries wherein you could get the SelectedItem (in our case ChartInfo) and from there you could do the requery.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helpme. and I hadn't thought the zoom in that way. Thanks.

Comment: @Clerks - if the answer helped you don't forget to vote it up and mark it as the accepted answer of your question :)